# How to merge three arrays in visual basic?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, for-loop

I would like merge three arrays in one array.

```
Dim arr() = 1 4 7 10 
Dim arr2() = 2 5 8 11
Dim arr3() = 3 6 9 12

Dim arr4()

for i=0 to ubond.(arr1)+2

??????????????
Next

The result should be arr4()= {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12}
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just concatenate and sort them with LINQ:

```
Dim arr4 = arr.Concat(arr2).Concat(arr3).OrderBy(Function(x) x)
```

Whether or not you call `.ToArray()` is optional and depends what you do with arr4. If you will enumerate it with a foreach loop you can leave it like above. If you will random access it or pass it round as an array of int then call ToArray on it

Make sure you `Imports System.Linq`

---

If you don't want to use LINQ, a simple loop:

```
Dim arr4() as New Integer(arr.Length * 3 - 1)

For x = 0 to arr.Length - 1 Step 1
  arr4(3*x) = arr(x)
  arr4(3*x+1) = arr2(x)
  arr4(3*x+2) = arr3(x)
Next x
```

This works completely differently - the LINQ version would have made an array of 1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9 and then sorted it, this one puts the bits in the right order naturally, but if your data didn't sort this way the two approaches would produce different outputs!